# Thread safety in static methods and variables

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, thread-safety, singleton

I was under the impression that static initialization is thread safe by default. Is that correct? Also consider the below example of singleton pattern.

```
public sealed class SingletonDemo
{
    private static readonly SingletonDemo instance = new SingletonDemo();    
    private SingletonDemo()
    {}
    public static SingletonDemo Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Is above example thread safe? If yes why? If No why?

Comment: See also: [Jon Skeet: Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) -- So in your code, all you'd need to add is an empty static constructor (`static SingletonDemo() {}`) to have the "fourth version" which would be thread safe.

Comment: Thnx Corak for the comment however I think adding static constructor would bring laziness and I am curious for the thread safety instead.

Answer (score 3):

> I was under the impression that static initialization is thread safe by default. Is that correct?

Yes, in terms of initialization - unless you use reflection to call the type initializer again, etc. Of course, there can then be multiple threads accessing the singleton at a time, so you need to make sure that *instance* members are thread-safe.

Note that with C# 6, the code can be simplified to:

```
public sealed class SingletonDemo
{
    public static SingletonDemo Instance { get; } = new SingletonDemo();    
    private SingletonDemo() {}
}
```

The type initialization rules of the CLR ensure that:

- The type is only initialized once
- While the type is being initialized in one thread, other threads trying to access it block
- There is a memory barrier after type initialization is completed, so any threads accessing the variable after type initialization has completed will see the right value

With the code as it is, laziness is *not* guaranteed - in other words, `SingletonDemo` may be initialized even if it's never actually used (e.g. because a method is called which *conditionally* uses it, but the condition isn't hit). To make it fully lazy, you could either use `Lazy<T>` or a static initializer:

```
public sealed class SingletonDemo
{
    public static SingletonDemo Instance { get; } = new SingletonDemo();    
    private SingletonDemo() {}
    private static SingletonDemo() {}
}
```

Comment: Thnx Jon Skeet for the response but one question still hits my mind that whether adding a static constructor is for laziness or thread safety? as both are independent things.

Comment: So the point when a static field gets initialized can vary according to whether the type has a static constructor or not? *Edit*: Found it answered in your article: "Static constructors in C# are specified to execute only when an instance of the class is created or a static member is referenced."

Comment: @PrakashTripathi: It only changes the laziness.